# Export document as HTML using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in .Net?

Tags: c#, html, ms-word, export, office-interop

I am trying to export a word document in HTML using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`. Unfortunately the only formats supported for export are PDF and XPS. Is there a way to work around this and force export to html or should I rather use COM?

any library that would allow me to export into HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Document.SaveCopyAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.savecopyas.aspx) with [wdFormatHTML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839952.aspx). Recording a macro when you save the word document as HTML should help you figure out the parameters.